# Dojo HorizontalSliders lose functionality upon subsequent instantiation

Tags: dojo, slider, dijit.form

My code is a for loop which creates 5 unique `HorizontalSliders`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    dom.byId('ui').innerHTML += '<div id="slider_' + i + '"></div>';
    var slider = new HorizontalSlider({
        value: 100,
        minimum: 0,
        maximum: 100,
        style: 'width:300px;'
    }, 'slider_' + i);
    slider.startup();
}
```

However, only the last created HorizontalSlider functions properly.

The other HorizontalSliders would not even slide, let alone listen to an onChange event if I gave it one.

Why is this the case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All dijit in dojo have a `placeAt(domnonde)` method , in which you can use directly on each instantiated slider . (placeAt acccept both domeNode or string id in the param)
See below  working snippet :

```js
require([
  "dijit/form/HorizontalSlider",
], function(
  HorizontalSlider
) {

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    
    var slider = new HorizontalSlider({
      value: 100,
      minimum: 0,
      maximum: 100,
      style: 'width:300px;'
    }).placeAt("ui");
    slider.startup();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="claro">
  <div id="ui"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @AsherCheeYiLiang does this fix yuor problem :)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

I was mistaken in source of problem, so I changed 'why' part of answer, but I'll leave code here, because it's working and solves problem.

```
require([
    "dijit/form/HorizontalSlider",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (
  HorizontalSlider, 
  dom
){

  var sliders = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  var getSlider = function(i) {
    return new HorizontalSlider({
                value: 100,
                minimum: 0,
                maximum: 100,
                style: 'width:300px;'
            });
  }

  var placeAndStart = function (s) {
    s.placeAt('ui');
    s.startup();
  }

  sliders.map(getSlider).forEach(placeAndStart)

});
```

[Js Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rok2ursc/14/)

Comment: @BooBerr'ita, oh, thanks, now I see how it should look :)